# How to erase by luminosity/brightness?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to erase by hand with a brush or eraser tool, but I only want darker colors to be erased. For example, if a pixel under the brush is 100% black (luminosity=0), it would get 100% erased (turned to opacity/alpha=0%). If a pixel is a dark blue (say luminosity=20), it would get 80% erased (alpha=20%). If a pixel is solid white, it would be untouched (alpha=100%).

This question is about photoshop, but an answer that works in a different but free graphics program will be just as good or better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use Photoshop Knockout layers in conjunction with BlendIf.

Here I have a Radial Gradient that punches a hole in the `Group 1` group. It's set to `Shallow Knockout` to act only inside that group, fill is set to 0% to ignore the layer contents (black color):

[image]

Next if I change the Blend If `Underlying Layer` slider, this gradient starts to lose transparency if the layer below is darker or brighter that specific value:

[image]

An example where a letter `A` punches through pixel values that are stronger that 80% (`Underlying Layers` is set to 204: 255*0.8)
[image]